# MQ vs. branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs, mercurial-queue

I've been working with Mercurial now for some time. When making (private) changes to some third party software, in the past I always created a separate named branch for these changes. When the upstream code updates, I simply merge it into my named branch.

Today I read about MQ (Mercurial Queues - chapters [12](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) and [13](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/advanced-uses-of-mercurial-queues.html)). I think I understood the concept behind MQ, so my question is:

Is there any advantage of MQ over (named) branches in Mercurial (for my scenario)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main advantage of MQ over named branches are:

- You can revise your patches. This lets you edit history and so you can maintain a clean and logical series of patches on top of the upstream code: if you notice a mistake in a patch you refresh the patch instead of making a new commit.
- The changes in your patches will be cleanly separated from the changes made upstream. When you merge two branches, you mixing the two streams of development. This makes it difficult to see the changes you've made without also seeing the changes coming in from the upstream branch.
- The patch names are transient. When you `hg qfinish` an applied patch, there's no trace of the patch name left in the commit. So you can use MQ without coordinating first with the upstream repository since they'll never notice MQ.
- You avoid merges. Instead of merging with the latest code from upstream, you [rebase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) your applied patches. This gives you a simpler history. The history is obviously fake since you pretend that you made all your patches *after* seeing the code from upstream — when infact you made it in parallel with upstream and later *moved* your patches to the tip of upstream.
- You have no permanent branch name in the changesets. People sometimes [treat named branches as disposable](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StandardBranching#What_not_to_do) and become upset when they realize that a named branch is fixed in history. (You can actually set the branch name with `hg branch` before pushing patches so this point is not so bad.)

Disadvantages of MQ are:

- It's an extra tool to learn. It's powerful, but it also gives you more opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot. Running `hg qdelete` will really *delete* the patch and so you can throw away data. (I think this is fine, but we've had a Git user coming to our mailinglist complaining about this.)
- You make it much harder to collaborate with others. You *can* turn `.hg/patches` into a repository and push/pull patches around between repositories but it's difficult to do that if you're more than a single developer. The problem is that you end up merging patches if more than one persons refreshes the same patch.
- You have no permanent branch name in the changesets. If you're using named branches right and use stable, long-term branch names, then you will miss that when using MQ.

Comment: You can achieve those same results with rebase though.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: oh, yeah. I was more focussing on how MQ *forces* you t o rebase the patches — merging is not allowed with MQ. Let me expand the answer a bit.

Comment: MQCollab extension make collaboration by MQ-patches *really nice*

Comment: I never rebase MQ-patches. Just qpop all, pull, qpush, edit patch if needed. What I do wrong?

Comment: @LazyBadger: rebasing instead of `qpush --all` will let you use merge tools to resolve conflicts.

Comment: More details, pls?! Maybe in answer directly - it will be useful for all MQers

Comment: @LazyBadger You can [rebase a patch queue](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-02-11-merging-mq-patches-with-rebase/). Rebasing uses merges internally and you will thus get merge-tool support when rebasing. You don't get that when using qpush.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It depends. Personally I dislikes mercurial branching system, and I try to avoid it when I can (using pushed bookmarks instead of branch).

MQ is a great tool, with great power and great pitfalls. You can also consider using [pbranch](http://arrenbrecht.ch/mercurial/pbranch/).

MQ is a great tool if you need to produce and maintain a patch-set for a project, something like adding feature-x to a project and keeping patches updated with the upstream code.

Bookmarks (or branches if you like) are good for short-development task that require to be merged into the upstream code.